# Java - Using generics to generate random objects?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to use generics to create an object that can be a type of T, is this possible?

```
public class SoapObjectToModel <T> {

    public ArrayList<T> convert(SoapObject soapObject) {

        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
        // Somehow initialize an object of type T

        }
}
```

Comment: How many times has this been asked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot create an object of type `T`.

Always remember you could always have `SoapObjectToModel<MyAbstractClass>`, and what will happen if you try to create `T`? Will it create an abstract class?

As a workaround, you might want to pass an element of type `T` as a parameter, and use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) to create a new object, or even better - have a look at the [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Comment: You can do this with java reflection. In your example case it will throw an exception, but generally it is possible

Comment: @Tim: How can you do it without a concreat object of `T`, you will need to have an instance - and then you can do it - as I mentioned, or use the factory pattern

Comment: Who down votes this? Nothing wrong with this answer and only lacks the reference to 'type erasure'.

Comment: @Tim: No, you can't do this with reflection, because in this case, there is no way to get hold of a class object corresponding to T.

Comment: it is irrelevant because even if you have `SoapObjectToModel<SomeNonAbatractClass>`, it wouldn't work

Comment: @newacct: true, but I just find it as a good memory aid for java beginners. I know it helped me remember this issue when I just started using java.

Answer (score 1):

Using the factory pattern as suggested by amit is a very good solution to this problem and it is also the general solution that is guaranteed to work. However, the suggested alternative of using reflection may be easier in some cases. This is a practical example of how reflection could be used in your particular case:

```
class SoapObjectToModel<T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    public SoapObjectToModel(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ArrayList<T> convert(SoapObject soapObject) {

        try {
            ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
            result.add(type.newInstance());
            return result;
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```